# Remove value on click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a javascript that will change the value of anotif to 0 once clicked:

```
Approved:<?php if($anotif<1){
    echo 0;
} else { 
    echo '<a class="anotif" onClick="validator()" href="?anotif">'.$anotif.'</a>';
} ?><br/>
```

But I am not sure how do that, considering that I'm so new in javascript. I've googled around a bit but I wasn't able to find the answer.

```
function validator(){
    if(document.anotif.clicked){ // I'm not really sure if this is correct.
        // if clicked, change value to zero
}
```

To be more precise, I want it to look like this once clicked:
From:
  Approved:3
To:
  Approved:0

```
Approved:<?php if($anotif<1){
    echo 0;
} else { 
    echo '<a class="anotif" onClick="validator()" href="?anotif">'.$anotif.'</a>';
} ?><br/>
```

This code will lead me to ?anotif for me to view some data from the database in a table. Once approved:

is clicked, it must be set to zero at the same time I move to the other page.

The problem is it requires refreshing for it to be set to 0 by the system.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
$firstname =  getuserfield('txtFname');
$lastname = getuserfield('txtLname');
echo 'Hello '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'.<br/>';

$anotif = 0;
$dnotif = 0;
$anotif = $anotif + getuserfield('approved_notif');
$dnotif = $dnotif + getuserfield('disapproved_notif');
?>
<h3>Notifications:</h3>
Approved:<?php if($anotif<1){echo 0;} else { echo '<a class="anotif" onClick="validator(this);" href="?anotif">'.$anotif.'</a>';}?><br/> //problem is over here
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['anotif'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hrf_leave WHERE empid = '$empid' AND formStatus = 1 AND checked = 0";
    $query_run = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>Type of Leave</th>
    <th>Specific Reason</th>
    <th>Date From</th>
    <th>Date To</th>
    <th>Number of Days</th>
    </tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){ 
        $leave_id = $record['leave_id'];
        echo "<td>" . $record['type_of_leave'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['specific_reason'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['date_from'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['date_to'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['num_of_days'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $query2 = "UPDATE hrf_leave SET checked=1 WHERE leave_id = $leave_id";
        if($query_run2 = mysql_query($query2)){ 
            $anotif = 0;
            $query3 = "UPDATE hrms_emp_info SET approved_notif=$anotif WHERE empid = $empid";
            if($query_run3 = mysql_query($query3)){
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
Disapproved:<?php if($dnotif<1){echo 0;} else { echo '<a href="?dnotif">'.$dnotif.'</a><br/>';} ?> //and here
<?php
if(isset($_GET['dnotif'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hrf_leave WHERE empid = '$empid' AND formStatus = 2 AND checked=0"; 
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);
    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>Type of Leave</th>
    <th>Specific Reason</th>
    <th>Date From</th>
    <th>Date To</th>
    <th>Number of Days</th>
    </tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){
        $leave_id = $record['leave_id'];
        echo "<td>" . $record['type_of_leave'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['specific_reason'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['date_from'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['date_to'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['num_of_days'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $query2 = "UPDATE hrf_leave SET checked=1 WHERE leave_id = $leave_id";
        if($query_run2 = mysql_query($query2)){ 
            $dnotif = $dnotif-1;
            $query3 = "UPDATE  hrms_emp_info SET disapproved_notif=$dnotif WHERE empid = $empid";
            if($query_run3 = mysql_query($query3)){ 
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Once it's clicked it will go to `?anotif` so why should you change the value of anotif in JavaScript if the page is refreshing anyway?

Comment: I get your point, but how should I do it? If I need to use ajax, how can I do it? I'm really sorry, I'm having a hard time learning ajax and js atm,

Answer (score 2):

You could change your anchor a bit like this:

```
<a class="anotif" onClick="return validator(this)" href="?anotif">
```

Then change the `validator()` function like this:

```
function validator(element)
{
    // element is clicked already, so you can change its value

    element.innerHTML = '0';

    // prevent click from changing page
    return false;
}
```

<strike>However, the real problem here is that the page will be changed to `?anotif` and whatever you changed will be wasted effort.</strike>
Updated the code with a way to prevent the click from changing the page and just reducing the number to '0'.

Comment: Use `onClick="validator(this); return false;"` to avoid loading new page. To change PHP variable you have to use an ajax call.

Comment: @Tissue Note that ghaxx mentioned, you can prevent the page from changing, but in that case PHP won't get called ... you would need to give more background in your question to help you further.

Comment: Alright, I will edit my question to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Tissue I don't think that swath of PHP code was very helpful; when the `?anotif` link is clicked, should the page refresh or not? If not, you're looking at Ajax. If so, the page refresh could set the value to 0.

Comment: It will move to ?anotif wherein you can view the list of data from the database. But I want it to change to zero as I move to ?anotif.

If i try refreshing the page (?anotif), it will clear out the table since it is meant to be like that, those data can only be viewed once.

Comment: @Tissue Then my code *should* work, granted that you remove `return false;` from the function.

Comment: I tried your code without the return false; 

It changes to 0 onClick, but once it moved to ?anotif, it returned the value back to what it was, not 0. But refreshing the page seems to work just fine, which is not fine for my system.

Comment: @Tissue Without knowing how that value actually gets reduced, this is purely cosmetic. Some round-trip to the server is required to get it reduced afaict.

Comment: It gets deducted each time the query loops
$dnotif = $dnotif-1; until it reaches 0